# Getting current file

Tags: vb.net, system.reflection

I know in vb.net you can use `System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.ToString` to get the name of the current method you are in. However, is there a way to use `System.Reflection...` to get the name of the current file you are in?

So if you had a file in the project named `blah.vb` I would want `System.Reflection...` to return `blah.vb`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.Reflection.Assembly` to find the file name of the current assembly.  There are several applicable methods to choose from:

- [`GetEntryAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Returns the assembly that started the process (the executable)
- [`GetCallingAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Returns the assembly that called the current method
- [`GetExecutingAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - Returns the assembly in which the current method resides

I suspect that what you want is `GetExecutingAssembly`.  All of those methods return an `Assembly` object through which you can get the file path, like this:

```
Dim myFilePath As String = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

For what it's worth, if you need get the file name of the executable, but it's *not* a .NET assembly (because you're in a .NET library invoked via COM), then the above method won't work.  For that, the best option would be to grab the first argument from the command line, like this:
    Dim myComExeFile As String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()(0)